# Merge two dataframe with duplicate entries but with different values

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I will be able to explain with example what I need to achieve:
[image]

Though both dataframe have duplicates, values of the column 'first_name' are different. Now I want to merge both, with output something like this:

[image]

```
df_a.merge(df_b, on='subject_id', how='left')
```

pandas merge will not give this output because of duplicates. how can I get my desired output or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need helper coumns created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and used it for `merge`, last remove it:

```
df_a['g'] = df_a.groupby('subject_id').cumcount()
df_b['g'] = df_b.groupby('subject_id').cumcount()
df_a.merge(df_b, on=['subject_id', 'g'], how='left').drop('g', axis=1)
```